# Use WebClient.DownloadString with https uri using MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I run my application locally or type in the the (original) url in my browser, it works. When I publish it to my domain it doesn't:

```
string responseString;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    responseString = client.DownloadString("https://cp.customerlog.in:5656/api/client/command.php?key=123456&hash=123456&action=info&bw=true");
}
```

Error message:
    `unable to connect to the remote server`

I added the following line (at the beginning), which produced another error:
    `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; // all other (except Ssl3) ProtocolTypes produced the same error as above (unable to...)`

Error Message:
    `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.`

Comment: Can you `ping cp.customerlog.in` from the domain?

Comment: Sounds like your host doesn't allow outbound SSL connections.

Comment: If you are not afraid going into some low level: use a network protocol analyser such as WireShark; it is free. https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Ok, thank you,  Mike McCaughan's answer is probably true. Anyone knows whether it is possible (I'm hosting on godaddy)?